# java hibernate one to many "Hibernate mapping files and POJOs from database"

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pojo

I'm using Hibernates "Hibernate mapping  files and POJOs from database" to transform tables to POJOs. The problem is that the table relations do not automatically create a "Set ..." property. What do I have to do to make Hibernate work with this?

Example table structure:
[image: Example table structure]

Edit:
So for example Stock has a property "Set StockDailyRecord". Hibernate should add them automatically. An example of what I mean can be found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_set_mapping.htm

Comment: provide more details, what "Set..." property?

Comment: What do you mean by "Set ..." property?

Comment: If you meant the Java entity setXXX methods, you need to create them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the job of the developer to create the setters and getters for the java objects.

Assuming you have a field

```
private Set<Stock> stockDailyRecord;
```

Normally you would create a pair:

```
public Set<Stock> getStockDailyRecord();
public void setStockDailyRecord( Set<Stock> newRecordSet);
```

And then you would also normally create a convenience method

```
public void addDailyRecord( Stock newRecord)
{
    this.getStockDailyRecord().add(newRecord);
}
```

Hint: most IDEs will create the getter/setters for you after you define the fields.

Comment: I want it automatically filled by:
"    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")"
When I execute it, it is still an empty hashmap

Comment: When you load the object from the database, the collection will not be null, it will be a lazy loading container. Then when you dereference the collection, it will load any (if any) related objects. But when you create the object yourself, you need to populate that field yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you only need a getter for relations.

```
  Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() { return stockDailyRecords; }
```

and then

```
  StockDailyRecord aStockDailyRecord = ...
  stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(aStockDailyRecord);
```